# Validating a bootstrap 3 radio button in ASP.net form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have been working on this asp.net form getting jquery validation/unobtrusive validation working but have exausted my google.com skills and have yet to find an answer.

I can't seem to get the jquery validation working on the radio buttons. Any help would be greatly apreciated

asp.net code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, true, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "IsMonetary" }, { "data-val", "true" } })
        Add $ amount
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, false, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "IsNotMonetary" } })
        Not this time jackson
    </label>
</div>

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x)
```

Output html:

```
<form action class="form-horizontal" id="recipientForm" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn_group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input id="IsMonetary" name="IsMonetary" type="radio" data-val="true" data-val-required="*" value="true">Add $ award</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input id="IsNotMonetary" name="IsMonetary" type="radio" value="false" data-val-required="*">Not this time</label>
        </div>
       <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="IsMonetary" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <input id="derp" name="derp" data-val="true" data-val-required=”Required” />
    <span data-valmsg-for="derp" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right loading" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/NPMwh/)* Note the external files, if you would like to view them please check: [Here (github link)](https://github.com/Mutmatt/fiddle_files)

Comment: Regarding the order of your javascript includes: I'm not sure how you can include a file called `jquery.validate.unobtrusive-support-for-bootstrap.js` _before_ `bootstrap.js`.

Comment: Swapped them around.  JSFiddle does last in last loaded, was not really going straight logic when uploading them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
$('form').validate();

$('form').on('submit', function () {
    console.log($(this).validate());
    console.log("valid: " + $(this).valid());
    //return false;
});
```

**You do not need a submit handler.**

The jQuery Validate plugin...

a) captures the `click` of the submit button,
b) captures the other mouse events that trigger validation,
c) does the validation,
d) prevents the submit if invalid,
e) and then allows the submit if valid

... all *automatically*.

Basic usage:  http://jsfiddle.net/xjXhN/

---

Also, `.validate()` is the *initialization* method of the plugin and only gets called once on page load.  Doesn't the `unobtrusive` plugin along with ASP already handle this initialization automatically?

Comment: hey sparky do you think you could take a second look, i've updated the question with a correct fiddle with an input and radio button

Comment: @Mutmatt, I still don't know what you're trying to do but when I delete the `bootstrap.css` file from your fiddle, it shows that the validation plugin is working.  http://jsfiddle.net/NPMwh/22/